# Distinct values for first/last date in group

Tags: database, vba, excel, pivot-table

I have data in the format below with unique ID's in Column A, but these ID's could appear on multiple rows representing repeat transactions against that individual. In col B i have the datetime stamp of that transaction, and in Col C, the name of the transaction;

```
Col A      Col B                  Col C
ABC1       15/02/2018 16:26       Apple
ABC1       14/02/2018 11:26       Pear
ABC1       13/02/2018 09:11       Pear
ABC2       15/02/2018 16:26       Orange
ABC2       14/02/2018 11:26       Pear
ABC2       13/02/2018 09:11       Apple
ABC3       15/02/2018 16:26       Grape
ABC3       14/02/2018 11:26       Orange
ABC3       13/02/2018 09:11       Apple
```

I'm trying to pivot this data with MIN and MAX criteria on the datestamp to get the count of how many records had which transaction in Col C as their first transaction, how many had X transaction in Col C as their latest transaction etc, the aim to finalise the data in something like this;

MIN (first) transactions:

```
Distinct Count Col A    Col C
1                       Pear
2                       Apple
```

MAX (last) Transactions:

```
Distinct Count Col A    Col C
1                       Grape
1                       Orange
1                       Apple
```

Is there a way to do this with Pivot tables I'm missing? I'm working with several million rows of data here so manipulating via a pivot is easier for me to do (data loaded via power query) than using a formula or something. I can concatenate columns during the load process if needed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use helper columns as this will allow you to use page filters for max and min rather than relying on ordering each column in question.

Set your data up as a table. Then add a max column and a min column.

Max column formula:

```
=IF([@[Col B]]=MAX([Col B]),1,0)
```

Min column formula:

```
=IF([@[Col B]]=MIN([Col B]),1,0)
```

Create 2 pivots. 1 for max and 1 for min and put the max or min in the page field and filter on 1 (i.e. date is max or min of source values)

[image: Create pivot example]

Order the Column C by count of Column of Column C (the fruit name column), in which ever way you see fit. Ascending for the min if you are interested in the fruit with the smallest count for the min date.

Final outcome:

[image: Image of data]

You can always remove unwanted fields e.g. Column B to get the exact same look:

[image: Column B (DateTime) removed]

### Edit:

If you want to show the count of each fruit, by ID, for the minimum date for that ID you can use lookup table pivot(s)

An example lookup table pivot for minimum values for each ID

[image: Lookup table with minimum dates for each ID]

You then reference this table in your source table, in a helper column, using index match to retrieve the minimum date and compare against the date in your data table for the same ID:

Formula in helper column (`MinMatch`):

```
=IF(INDEX(LookupMin!B:B,MATCH(A2,LookupMin!A:A,0))=[@Date],1,0)
```

[image: Data and pivot for count of min]

Note: This would be a lot easier if you created a unique key of ID & Fruit and lookup against that.

The helper column formula is:

```
=IFERROR(IF([@[Col B]]=INDEX(LookupMin!$A:$E,MATCH([@[Col A]],LookupMin!$A:$A,0),MATCH([@[Col C]],LookupMin!$4:$4)),1,0),"")
```

`LookupMin`! is the sheet with the minimum pivot in.

Note that I have used a pivot on the data table to see count of each fruit, on the minimum date for each ID.

You could have used a formula instead, but then  you would have repeating sums i.e see Column F

[image: Formula to get count of fruit on min date by ID]
Formula in E (then dragged down):

```
=SUMIFS([MinMatch],[Fruit],C2,[ID],A2)
```

Finally, if you then decided you wanted earliest date for ID and fruit you could change the lookup as follows:

[image: Additional lookup]

Comment: This in an inventive solution QHarr and thank you for taking the time to respond to my question. In actual fact with my data I have hundreds of thousands of different IDs in column A and millions of timestamps in column B, so such an outcome pivot would be too large still. Is there a way to rework this by pivoting the final outcome on column C as there are only about 20 'fruit'.

Comment: I need the minimum and maximum formulas on a per unique ID basis e.g. some kind of max if statement where its the highest or lowest datetime value for that record ID I believe. This would be a helper column added in at the power query level so I could quickly apply it to the 12 million rows.

Comment: Your shown output is not on a unique ID basis however I have updated my answer with an edit at the end. Apologies I don't have time now to tidy it up further. The maximum process is the same as for the minimum.